# Code::Block not creating a Debug Build?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, build, codeblocks

I have had this problem with Code::Blocks that when my project is still overly small (even 10 lines long), and I go to build "debug", the file will not be created. It doesn't tell me this in Code::Blocks. Basically, I go to hit play, and it will ask me to build my project even though I had clicked the "build" button about 2 seconds before...

It works fine with release build, however...

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
      cout << "Hello" << endl;
      cout << "World!" << endl;
      return 0;
 }
```

Even a program as simple as that does work in release build, but not debug build (the file gets deleted).

Have I got something wrong with my settings? Note it  was like this ever since I downloaded it, and I had no idea what was wrong (as it does debug build by default, so I didn't know I could use release build)

Anyone know?

Edit: yes, the file is part of a project file

Comment: Have you included it in a project ?

Comment: @ameyCU Yes, I'm not stupid

Comment: @Mathew I just asked if this file belongs to active project or not ?

Comment: it does, I go to create the new project add a few lines, it works, add a few more, then it doesn't work in debug build :/

Comment: @Mathew  So you are saying that  xyz.cpp gets deleted ?

Comment: (sorry I now realise that what i said was rude :s) and yes it just disappears from bin/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you selected 'Console application' when creating the project instead of 'Empty Project'.

Comment: I don't think there will be any problem until file's extension is correct in it. File  will compile .

Comment: Oh okay, it's always fine to discard silly mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

Also, when you create the project from new, make sure that the:-
 'Create "Debug" configuration'
is enabled, and has valid paths showing etc.

On the previous dialog, where the new project tool asks for folder paths etc to put stuff, make sure you give it somewhere valid (that exists) etc, or make a new folder for it.

I've just built and run your bit of code as Debug and Release just fine, in C::B 16.01 on Windows.   As a "Console" application.  Using the defaults, other than I created a new folder for it all.

Regards.

DJB

Comment: On top of what HappyCoder said, give examples of valid paths, folders etc as it makes it a lot easier for people to understand.